# Regex does not match but seems to be correct

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching, python-3.3

I have a very weird problem:

Using the same regex matches in several online services, but not in my local python 3.3 instance.

```
re.search("ajaxHandler\('(?P<fp>[A-Z0-9]+)",rawdata).group("fp")
```

where rawdata is

```
<select name="F4542661421192HPAUS" onchange="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F4542661421185WLRZY=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value), null, null, null)">[... blabla ...]</select>
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce this:

```
Python 3.3.0 (v3.3.0:bd8afb90ebf2, Sep 29 2012, 10:57:17) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AM
D64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> rawdata="""<select name="F4542661421192HPAUS" onchange="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F4542661421185WLRZY=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value), null, null, null)">[... blabla ...]</select>"""
>>> re.search("ajaxHandler\('(?P<fp>[A-Z0-9]+)",rawdata).group("fp")
'F4542661421185WLRZY'
```

Comment: Perhaps it is a encoding problem

Comment: first i thought it, too. but in the string are only ASCII symbols. If i try exact what @tim-pietzcker tried, it seems to work. If i put these three lines into a file and loading them, it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "putting them in a file and loading them"? Do you mean importing them as a Python module, or loading the regex from a text file? How exactly are you doing this?

Comment: I wrote your commands with a normal editor into a textfile, added shebang and executed them with "python3.3 textfile.py"

Comment: What was the error message? You did remove the `>>>`s, right?

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a bit more precise on your problem? I cannot reproduce this error either:

```
rawdata = """<select name="F4542661421192HPAUS" onchange="liftAjax.lift_ajaxHandler('F4542661421185WLRZY=' + encodeURIComponent(this.value), null, null, null)">[... blabla ...]</select>"""

print(re.search("ajaxHandler\('(?P<fp>[A-Z0-9]+)",rawdata).group("fp"))

Output: F4542661421185WLRZY
```

Maybe something went wrong with your rawdata type? Without the """ I got a nontype error because ' and " do not work without \" though this shouldn't be your problem?

Comment: Everything was correct. I've tried the same files on another computer (only to check if my python is broken or something) => yes it was broken. I have reinstalled it completely, now it works and i don't know why - but working is working.

Comment: Allright! It's what you least expect.. But new installs often get rid of all malfunctions/settings you changed over the months/years.